# Page Type showing "Home page" or "page" randomly

Tags: wagtail, wagtail-admin

I followed [Official Wagtail Docs](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/getting_started/integrating_into_django.html#integrating-wagtail-into-a-django-project) to integrate freshly installed Wagtail into existing Django project.
I added customized `HomePage` class in existing Django's `models.py`.

```
# myDjangoProject/models.py

class HomePage(Page):
    template = "homepage.html"
    content = RichTextField()
    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
        FieldPanel("content")
    ]
```

[image]
**Q1: In above screenshot, Why system default page `Welcome to Wagtail` is of `Page` TYPE, while newly created `New Page` is of `Home page` TYPE automatically ?**

[image]
**Q2: In above screenshot, Why Newly-created child page under system default page `Welcome to Wagtail` is of `Home page` surprisingly without any manual configuration ?**

[image]
**Q3: In above screenshot, why all newly-created pages automatically (no manual configuration required) inherited from my customized `HomePage` class in `MyDjangoProject/models.py` ? How is this reflected on source code level ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Page` class is the base class of all page types in Wagtail, but normally it wouldn't be desirable to let users create pages that are of the type `Page` rather than something more specific, because there's no way to add new content fields to it. For this reason, [the `is_creatable` attribute](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/reference/pages/model_reference.html#wagtail.core.models.Page.is_creatable) is set to false on `Page`, which means that new pages of that type can't be created through the admin interface. (This attribute is not inherited by subclasses, so any new page types you create will be `is_creatable = True` by default.)

The initial "Welcome" page is created as part of the migrations in the `wagtail.core` app. At this point, `Page` is the only page type that exists (since your HomePage model hasn't been defined yet), so that's the one Wagtail uses. It might seem a bit weird that the default page is not one that you can create yourself through the admin, but there's no real alternative (other than not providing a default page at all, which would make it harder for developers to see if their installation has worked).

(When setting up a brand new Wagtail project through `wagtail start`, the project template includes migrations to replace the initial `Page` instance with an instance of the supplied `HomePage` model, so in this case it's less confusing.)

After you defined your `HomePage` model, this became the only page type with `is_creatable = True`, and so the admin interface automatically selects this page type on adding a new page. When you add another page model alongside HomePage, you'll find that it prompts you to select a page type.

Comment: followed your advise to add another page model, now I can see the page type choice when adding Pages on Wagtail admin.  In summary,  "TYPE" of page on Wagtail admin reflects all user-defined page models.  through this question, I learned the role played by `is_creatable` in page model. thanks a lot.